# How to package Windows Mobile Application from Adobe AIR

Tags: apache-flex, windows-phone-7, adobe, flex4.5

am really confusing about How we can  package Windows Mobile Application from Adobe AIR ? or is there any way to create windows mobile application by using Adobe AIR ?
Currently we are having iOS & Android pack by using Adobe AIR. Am searching for a solution from last 2 days but still didn't get a solution for this..

Anybody can please help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Mobile is not supported by Adobe AIR